# Why do Static Methods & Enumerations have unexpected behavior in Xamarin Forms? Objects Passed to Static Methods become null & enums are stored as int

Tags: enums, static, xamarin.forms, null, encapsulation

I have been using C#/.NET/Visual Studio since 2000, but I just started working with Xamarin Forms recently. It's a pretty great platform, however I have run across a couple of issues that I cannot figure out. (I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community). I have been researching this behavior extensively, but have had absolutely no luck in obtaining a resolution. I have created a small application which easily reproduces both of these behaviors and would greatly appreciate any expertise that would help me fix my code so it works as expected. The two issues are these:

1) After creating a custom object using *new* in Xamarin Forms, the object is **not** *null*. However, if that object is passed via the parameter list into a **static** method, it becomes *null* inside the method. (Note: In my sample applications I placed the static method inside the *Form1* and *MainPage* classes. I did this only to simplify the samples. The behavior is the same when I put the static method into a separate utility class, either static class or normal class.)

2) Custom enumerations are treated as integers instead of the actual enumerated type. For example, if an instance of an enumerated type is given a value of the first item in the enumeration, its value is *0*, an integer. Whereas in a Windows application, the value would be the actual enumeration value (e.g., *EnumValue1*), and its type would be the enumerated type. This can be a problem if one is trying to do comparisons with strings. For example, *aEnum.ToString() == "EnumValue1"* will return *true* in a Windows application, but will return *false* in Xamarin Forms, because *aEnum.ToString()* will evaluate to *"0"*. This behavior also breaks the tenet of encapsulation in object-oriented programming, in that you aren't supposed to have to know the underlying implementation of a data type in order to properly use it.

Below is the code that reproduces the issues. There are 2 separate projects, one Windows Forms, the other Xamarin Forms. (The Xamarin Forms project was created with **.NET Standard** code sharing strategy). Both projects use 2 utility classes *Enumerations* and *CustObj*, where the only differences are the namespace definitions (*namespace WinFormApp.Utilities* and *namespace XamarinFormsApp.Utilities*, respectively). They both reside in a *Utilities* folder under their respective projects.

**Windows Forms "Form1.cs"**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WinFormApp.Utilities;

namespace WinFormApp
{
    partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // ENUMERATION TEST
            ACustomEnumeration aCE = ACustomEnumeration.EnumValue1;
            string aceStr = aCE.ToString();

            // PASSING OBJECT TO STATIC METHOD
            CustObj aCustObj = new CustObj();
            int ii = aCustObj.i;
            string ss = aCustObj.s;
            Form1.Foo(aCustObj);
        }

        public static void Foo(CustObj custObj)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Xamarin Forms "MainPage.xaml.cs"**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using XamarinFormsApp.Utilities;

namespace XamarinFormsApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // ENUMERATION TEST
            ACustomEnumeration aCE = ACustomEnumeration.EnumValue1;
            string aceStr = aCE.ToString();

            // PASSING OBJECT TO STATIC METHOD
            CustObj aCustObj = new CustObj();
            int ii = aCustObj.i;
            string ss = aCustObj.s;
            MainPage.Foo(aCustObj);
        }

        public static void Foo(CustObj custObj)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Utility class "Enumerations.cs"**

```
namespace WinFormApp.Utilities (or XamarinFormsApp.Utilities)
{
    public enum ACustomEnumeration
    {
        EnumValue1,
        EnumValue2
    }

    class Enumerations
    {
    }
}
```

**Utility class "CustObj.cs"**

```
namespace WinFormApp.Utilities (or XamarinFormsApp.Utilities)
{
    public class CustObj
    {
        public ACustomEnumeration _aCEMember;
        public int i;
        public string s;

        public CustObj()
        {
            this.i = 99;
            this.s = "Hello!";
        }
    }
}
```

When stepping through the **WinFormApp** in Visual Studio, one observes the following variables **before** the call to static method *Foo*:

1. **aCE** with value of **EnumValue1** and Type **ACustomEnumeration**
2. **aceStr** with Value of **"EnumValue1"** and Type **string**
3. **aCustObj** with Type **CustObj** and data members:

   - **_aCEMember** with Value of **EnumValue1** and Type **ACustomEnumeration**
   - **i** with Value of **99** and Type **int**
   - **s** with Value of **"Hello!"** and Type **string**
4. **ii** with Value of **99**
5. **ss** with Value of **Hello!**

**After** stepping into Foo, the parameter is as expected:

1. custObj with Type **CustObj** and data members:

   - **_aCEMember** with Value of **EnumValue1** and Type **ACustomEnumeration**
   - **i** with Value of **99** and Type **int**
   - **s** with Value of **"Hello!"** and Type **string**

All variables evaluate as expected. Enumerations evaluate as the actual enumerated value. The custom object is instantiated and its data members are given their appropriate initial values. When the object is passed into the static method, it is passed correctly as a reference type, and retains all of its data inside the method.

Conversely, when stepping through the **XamarinFormsApp** in Visual Studio, one observes the following variables **before** the call to static method *Foo*:

1. **aCE** with Value of **0** and Type **int** (violates encapsulation)
2. **aceStr** with Value of **"0"** and Type **string** (this demonstrates the problem with how enumerations are evaluated)
3. **aCustObj** with Type **CustObj** and data members:

   - **_aCEMember** with no Value or Type at all
   - **i** with no Value or Type at all
   - **s** with no Value or Type at all
4. **ii** with Value of **99**
5. **ss** with Value of **Hello!**

**After** stepping into Foo, the parameter is **NOT** as expected:

1. **custObj** with Value of **null** and Type **CustObj**

The problems with enumerations are fairly obvious. But I am very confused as to what is really going on with the custom object. It makes no sense that when I examine an object after its instantiation, that it doesn't show its data members as being initialized. Although it is strange how variables *ii* and *ss* are actually given the correct values.

More importantly, the fact that when I pass the object into the static method, it becomes **null**, is really mind-boggling.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is happenning, and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a debugger display problem?

Comment: After further investigation, it may have something to do with the debugging capabilities of the emulator plugged into Visual Studio.  I need to do more work to see exactly what is happenning.